# How to use the Imgur API in order to upload images and retrieve the image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, imgur

I'm fairly new to using APIs and sending AJAX requests.
How can I upload an image from my website to Imgur by using their API and how can I retrieve the URL?

```html
        
<!-- HTML form to submit the file -->

        <form onsubmit="UploadToImgur()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Thats what I got so far when it comes to the ajax request that is sen to imgur's API. As I said I'm new and I'm having a rough time figuring this out. So if anyone can help me out here that'd be great!

```
var imgfile = $("#file").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Client-ID ** CENSORED ** "},
    data: {image: imgfile},
    success: {},
    error: {},
});
```

Thank you in-advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't use the "Code Snippet" format for source code if the code cannot be executed directly on the page (like in your example). So maybe you can edit your question and fix this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me, I fixed it.